# Рассинхрон видео- и аудиодорожек при перекодировании ffmpeg

Tags: кодек, перекодировка, аудио, видео, ffmpeg

Произвожу перекодирование с помощью ffmpeg командой:

> ffmpeg -i in.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:3 -aspect 16:9 -c:v libxvid -b:v 1200k -s 720x400 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44.1k out.avi

то есть перекодирую из матроски (avc) в avi (xvid), при этом копируя 1-ю и 3-ю аудиодорожки с перекодированием их в mp3. Первая дорожка начинается с тишины (секунд 5) и на выходе перекодировщик эту тишину просто выкидывает, начиная аудиопоток с этой 5-й секунды. Таким образом получается громадный рассинхрон. Во второй дорожке этой тишины нет, и на выходе все корректно.

Может, есть какие-либо ключи, чтобы ffmpeg не игнорировал этот пропуск в начале, или другие способы побороть это? Заранее спасибо.

PS. Кстати, открыл этот файл в виртуалдабе и там при проигрывании точно так же пропущены эти первые 5 секунд, так что видимо проблема в декродере aac-кодека. Хотя странно, плеер использует ffdshow, в котором вроде та же самая библиотека libavcodec, что и в ffmpeg...

Comment: А что про этот файл говорит `ffprobe`? + Я бы попробовал указать ffmpeg явно, с какими входными потоками он работает и что они из себя представляют. + Теоретически может помочь параметр `-ss` до `-i` и такой же   перед `out.avi`.